# How bring react native app background to foreground? Firebase BackgroundMessageHandler

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-native-module

I can't bring the app to the foreground.

I tried to create the following service:

```
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log

class ForegroundService : Service() {

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "ForegroundService started")
        
      
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)


        stopSelf()

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ForegroundService"
    }
}
```

and after that I created the package and instance in MainActivity.kt

Finally in the firebase function, I tried calling the native module

```
         messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
            NativeModules.ForegroundServiceModule.startForegroundService();  
        }
      });
    }
```

but nothing happens, I notice that in the application stack, it takes the first position, but it has not yet taken the foreground

Application takes center stage